# If contains and if does not Contain a colon, select the number

Tags: if-statement, oracle11g

I have an `IF` statement that return the number, if there is a colon symbol in the string. Sometimes the string does not contain a colon symbol. I'm looking for an `else` statement that would select the only number "45061 if there is no colon in the string. A = Works when the string has a colon sign but I need some assistance with B, if the string does not have a colon.

A.

```
String/Text = OM_Account_Master_Slave~Account CP~3712011:Shared-001
```

B.

```
String/Text = OM_Account_Master_Slave~Account CP~45061Shared-001
```

A.

```
if(contains,":",Substring(Abbrev(),1,Subtract(Length(Abbrev()),11)))
```

Result = 3712011:Shared-001

B.

```
if(contains,":",Substring(Abbrev(),1,Subtract(Length(Abbrev()),11)))
else
```

Comment: How is this related to excel-vba?  Either way, can you not work off instances of "~" or do a reverse search of the string for "~" and then store the number until you encounter a letter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function GetNumber(r As Range) As Variant
    Dim v As String, capture As Boolean
    Dim i As Long, t As String

    v = r.Value
    GetNumber = ""
    If v = "" Then Exit Function
    t = ""
    capture = False

    For i = 1 To Len(v)
        m = Mid(v, i, 1)
        If IsNumeric(m) Then
            t = t & m
            capture = True
        Else
            If capture Then Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    If Len(t) > 0 Then
        GetNumber = CLng(t)
    End If
End Function
```

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

```
=GetNumber(A1)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**